# How to add isFavourite in json response - using laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am getting response of folder against the docId

My Controller code:

```
               public function getFolders(Request $request)
{
    $doctorId = $request->input('doctor_id');

    $folder =  DB::table('folder_details')
                ->join('doctor_favourite_folder','folder_details.folder_id','=','doctor_favourite_folder.id')
                ->select('doctor_favourite_folder.id','doctor_favourite_folder.folder_name')
                ->where('folder_details.doctor_id',$doctorId)->get();

    $resultArray = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'Folder detail by doctorId!', 'data' => $folder];

    return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

My Response:

```
             {
"status": true,
"message": "Folder detail by doctorId!",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "folder_name": "Accu"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "folder_name": "PT"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "folder_name": "Chiro"
    }
]
        }
```

Now i want to show the these folders are favourite or not  like below

```
                {
        "id": 1,
        "folder_name": "Accu",
         "isFavourite": true or false
    },
```

How i can show this kind of response in each folder, Your help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: How do you know when `isFavorite` should be true or false ? Is this information stored somewhere ?

Comment: no this information is not storing anywhere

Comment: What value do you want to use for `isFavorite` ? `true` for each ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `isFavourite` data is not in the database but it is computed with some logic.

Then before creating your `$resultArray` you can do something like this

```
$folder = $folder->map(function(&$f) {
    $f->isFavourite = ... // here you put your logic to compute that info.
});
```

Comment: Yes isFavouite is not in database

Comment: is there a way i can do this using a loop

Comment: Have you tried my code? 
That `->map()` is kind of a loop: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map

Answer (score 0):

you can try as @Leonardo Rossi and
You should declare `yourtable.isFavourite` in select:

```
select('doctor_favourite_folder.id','doctor_favourite_folder.folder_name', 'yourtable.isFavourite')
```

Sorry, i can't comment on his post

Comment: `foreach (json_decode(json_encode($folder), true) as $key => $item) { 
// any thing you input on your each item
} `